# Prove that any palindrome with an even number of digits is divisible by 11

Tags: number-theory, induction, palindrome

Confusing myself here, need some clarification..

First, we consider the palindrome $abccba$. We can see this can be written as
$$a(10^5 + 10^0) + b(10^4 + 10^1) + c(10^3 + 10^2) = a(10^5 + 1) + 10b(10^3 + 1) + 100c(10 + 1)$$ So essentially we see that all palindromes of even digits can be written in the form $x(10^{2k+1} + 1)$, i.e. we must show that any number of the form $(10^{2k+1} + 1)$ is divisible by $11$.

**Base case:** $10^{2(0)+1} + 1 = 10 + 1 = 11$, which is clearly divisible by $11$.

**Induction hypothesis:** Assume that $(10^{2k+1} + 1)$ is divisible by $11$, we work to show that $(10^{2(k+1)+1} + 1)$ is divisible by $11$. That is, $(10^{2k+3} + 1) = (10^2\cdot10^{2k+1} + 1) = \dots$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You might be making this too difficult. Do you know the basic test for divisibility by $11$?

Comment: This is easier once you know the divisibility test for 11. A number $a_na_{n-1}\cdots a_2a_1$ is divisible by 11 if and only if $a_1-a_2+a_3-a_4+\cdots+(-1)^na_n$ is divisible by 11. Can you prove this instead?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you have so far (aside from the typo where you wrote $2k+2$ when you meant $2k+3$). What can you say about the difference between $10^2 10^{2k+1}+ 1$ and $10^{2k+1}+1$?  (I mean literally, what happens when you subtract one from the other?)

Comment: Update: with your recent edit, you did not factor out $10^2$ correctly in the fourth line from the bottom.  However, if you multiply it out you'll see that you're only off by $99$, and this can easily be accounted for.

Comment: 10^2k+3 = ? then?

Comment: Like Erick said, the step you are missing is $10^{2k + 1}\cdot 100 + 1 = \left(10^{2k+1} + 1\right)\cdot 100 - 99$.  Otherwise your proof is fine.

Comment: Modulo 11 you have $10^{2 n + 1} \equiv (-1)^{2 k + 1} \equiv -1$

Comment: Shouldn't $100c(10^3+1)$ be $100c(10+1)$

Comment: See [Proof for divisibility rule for palindromic integers of even length](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57551/318073).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hint: Notice that $10^k=(-1)^k \pmod{11}$. So, for $k$ odd and $k'$ even, $10^{k} + 10^{k'}=0\pmod{11}$.

Answer (score 2):

Also, notice that in your inductive proof:

$10^{2k+3} + 1$ = $10^{(2k+2)+1}+1$ = $10^{2\overline{k} +1}+1$.