# Proof in mirror numbers / multiples of 3

Tags: integers

Happy 2019,

What's the proof for: any integer number subtracted by its *mirror* number is always a multiple of 3?

This is, abfc – cfba will always be a multiple of 3 (abfc, integer number).

Thanks

Comment: This has been solved here on this site. Extra for you: and $abfc+cfba$ will  always be a multiple of $11$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52600/divisibility-of-abcddcba-by-11?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write any general number $N_1=abfc$ as

$$=1000a + 100b +10f + c$$

Similarly you can write its mirror $N_2$ as

$$=1000c + 100f +10b + a$$

Subtracting $N_1$ and $N_2$

$$N_1 -  N_2= 999a +90b -90f - 999c = 3(333a + 30b - 30f - 333c)$$

As you can see this number is clearly divisible by $3$ irrespective of the values of $a,b,c,f$

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you prove and use the followinng lemma: if $n$ is an integer and $s$ is the sum of its digits, then $n-s$ is divisible by $9$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You may want to look at the following expression

$$(1000a+100b+10f+c)-(1000c+100f+10b+a)$$

Can you simplify the above expression and reach a conclusion? Note that the same idea applies regardless of how many digits the number has.

Comment: thanks. I'll try.