# On the GCD of a Pair of Fermat Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been working with the Fermat numbers recently, but this problem has really tripped me up. If the Fermat theorem is set as $f_a=2^{2^a}+1$, then how can we say that for an integer $b<a$, the $\gcd(f_b,f_a)=1$?

Answer (score 18):

Hint: Show that $f_b$ divides $f_a-2$.

Comment: Simpler than mine! I'm tempted to delete mine and just leave yours...

Comment: It's more "less detailed" than "simpler", I think. The question looked like it might be homework.

Comment: Perhaps: but you don't need to establish the precise formula like I did, but rather just use a "difference of $2^b$th powers" factorization, which is simpler.

Comment: Assuming that $b<a$, of course...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, but that's stipulated in the question.

Comment: Ah, I scanned for $b<a$ visually, but didn't re-read text. :)

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, It can be proved that $f_b$ divides $f_a-2$. But how it explains the desired proof.

Answer (score 15):

**Claim.** $f_n=f_0\cdots f_{n-1}+2$.

The result holds for $f_1$: $f_0=2^{2^0}+1 = 2^1+1 = 3$, $f_1=2^{2}+1 = 5 = 3+2$.

Assume the result holds for $f_n$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
f_{n+1} &= 2^{2^{n+1}}+1\\
&= (2^{2^n})^2 + 1\\
&= (f_n-1)^2 +1\\
&= f_n^2 - 2f_n +2\\
&= f_n(f_0\cdots f_{n-1} + 2) -2f_n + 2\\
&= f_0\cdots f_{n-1}f_n + 2f_n - 2f_n + 2\\
&= f_0\cdots f_n + 2,
\end{align*}$$
which proves the formula by induction. $\Box$

Now, let $d$ be a common factor of $f_b$ and $f_a$. Then $d$ divides $f_0\cdots f_{a-1}$ (because it's a multiple of $f_b$) and divides $f_a$. That means that it divides
$$f_a - f_0\cdots f_{a-1} = (f_0\cdots f_{a-1}+2) - f_0\cdots f_{a-1} = 2;$$
but $f_a$ and $f_b$ are odd, so $d$ is an odd divisor of $2$. Therefore, $d=\pm 1$. So $\gcd(f_a,f_b)=1$.

Comment: if i apply bezout identify on $F_b,F_b -$ I get is $x(F_b)+y(F_b -2)=2$ for$ x=1 $and  and $y=-1$ so Gcd will be 2. isn't it?

Comment: @mathophile: No; the gcd divides any linear combination, but just because a linear combination equals $2$ it does not mean the gcd is $2$. I mean, $2(3) -1(4) = 2$, but that does not mean $\gcd(3,4) = 2$. If you can get a linear combination equal to $1$, then that suffices, because the gcd will divide $1$, and so must *be* $1$. But with $2$, you cannot conclude you are done.

Comment: @mathopile: And since Fermat numbers are always **odd**, how could the gcd *possibly* be $2$? $2$ does not even divide them, let alone be the greatest common *divisor*. (And in any case, your calculation is wrong. For example, $F_2=17$, $F_1=5$, $F_0=3$. But $F_2-F_1\neq 2$.

Answer (score 6):

${\bf Hint}\rm\quad\ \ \gcd(c+1,\,\ c^{\large 2\,k}\!+1)\ =\ gcd(c+1,\:2)$

${\bf Proof}\rm\ \ \ mod\ c+1\!:\,\  c^{\large 2\,k}\!+1\: \equiv\ (-1)^{\large 2\,k}\!+1\:\equiv\ 2,\ \ {\rm by}\ \ c\equiv -1\quad {\bf QED}$

Specializing $\rm\,\ c=2^{\Large 2^{B}},\ \ 2\,k = 2^{\large \,A-B}\ \Rightarrow\ c^{\Large\, 2\,k} = 2^{\Large 2^{A}}\ $ immediately yields your claim.

**Remark** $\ $ Aternatively, one could employ that $\rm\:c^{\large 2\,k}\!+1\, =\, (c^{\large 2\,k}-1) + 2\:\equiv\: 2\pmod{c+1}\ $
by $\rm\ c+1\ |\ c^{\large 2}-1\ |\ c^{\large 2\,k}\!-1.\, $ But this requires some ingenuity, whereas the above proof does not, being just a trivial congruence calculation using the modular reduction property of the $\rm\:gcd,\:$ namely $\rm\ \gcd(a,b)\, =\, \gcd(a,\:b\ mod\ a),\:$ a reduction which applies much more *generally*. $ $ Said equivalently, the result follows immediately by applying a single step of the Euclidean algorithm. Notice how abstracting the problem a little served to greatly elucidate the innate structure.

Comment: More generally [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983281/242) for $\large \,\gcd(a^m+1,a^n+1)\ \ $

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to be cheeky and flesh out Henning Malkholm's answer, since it's been seven years since this was posted (so if it was indeed homework, it was probably due in by now) and his implicit solution is the best I've seen to this problem. If this bothers you, Henning, let me know and I'll take this down. (I don't have enough reputation to comment directly because I'm new here)

Suppose $b = a + k$ for $k$ a positive integer. Then by basic algebra
$$ F_b - 2 = 2^{2^b} - 1 = \left( 2^{2^{a}} \right)^{2^{k}} - 1$$
so, expanding using the geometric sum,
$$ F_b - 2 = \left( 2^{2^a} + 1 \right) \left\{ \left(2^{2^a}\right)^{2^k-1} - \left(2^{2^a}\right)^{2^k-2} + \cdots -1\right\} $$
So substituting the defining formula gives
$$ F_b - 2 = F_a \cdot \left( 2^{2^b-2^a} - \cdots - 1 \right) $$
In particular, $F_b-2$ is a multiple of $F_a$. However, successive odd numbers are relatively prime so no factor of $F_a$ can be a factor of $F_b$

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Fermat numbers belong to the companion Lucas sequence $V(3,2) = 2^{k} + 1$. Hence, all the prime factors of either $V_{p}$ where $p \neq 3$ is a prime, or $V_{2^{n}}$, are primitive; that is, they enter the sequence for the first time as factors at that very term.

So, as every prime factor of $f_{a}$ is primitive, it follows that $gcd(f_{a},f_{b}) = 1$  when $b < a$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=(f_n,f_{n+k})$ and keep in mind $d$ is odd. Now $d\mid f_n$ i.e. $$2^{2^n}\equiv -1\pmod d\implies 2^{2^{n+1}}\equiv 1\pmod d$$

Now we'll raise both sides to the $2^{k-1}$ power.
$$2^{2^{n+k}}\equiv 1\pmod d$$

But $p\mid f_{n+k}$ so $$-1\equiv 2^{2^{n+k}}\equiv 1\pmod d$$ Meaning $d\mid 2$ thus $d=1$.