# Prove that the elements of a sequence are pairwise co-prime

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

Hi I need help on this question:

Consider the sequence of positive integers an, for $n ≥ 1$, defined by
$a_n = 6^{2^n} + 1$.

(a) Prove that the elements of this sequence are pairwise co-prime, i.e. prove that
if $m$ is not $n$ then $gcd(a_m, a_n) = 1$.

(b) Show how this result, combined with the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic,
provides another proof that there are an infinite number of primes.

Hint: Begin the first part by proving that $a_n$ $|$ $(a_{n+1} − 2)$

I've tried proving that $a_n$ is a factor of $(a_{n+1} − 2)$ but now im not sure how to carry on to prove the $gcd$ is $1$.

Comment: $(a)$ is a special case of the first linked dupe, and $(b)$ follows by Euclid's method, as explained in my answer in the second linked dupe.

Comment: See also the Remark in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68666/242) for the Hint.