# $ 2^{2^1}+1, 2^{2^2}+1, \dots$ relatively prime to each other

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n=2^{2^{\alpha}}-1.$ We know that $$n=\frac{2^{2^{\alpha}}-1}{(2+1)}= (2^{2^{\alpha-1}}+1)(2^{2^{\alpha-2}}+1)\dots(2^{2^2}+1)(2^2+1).$$

My question is are the numbers $ 2^{2^1}+1, 2^{2^2}+1, \dots$ relatively prime to each other? Since I want to apply Chinease remainder theorem and find out a number $X$ such that $x^2\equiv -1 \mod n.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the GCD of a Pair of Fermat Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68653/on-the-gcd-of-a-pair-of-fermat-numbers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very factorization you give implies that $2^{2^i} + 1$ divides $2^{2^j}-1$ for all $j>i$. So if $2^{2^i}+1$ and $2^{2^j}+1$ have a common divisor $d$, then $d$ divides both $2^{2^j}-1$ and $2^{2^j}+1$, so it can only be $1$ or $2$. But wait, it can't be $2$ either, because $2^{2^j}+1$ is odd.