# Congruence mod $n+1$ of radix-$n$ integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct positive integers. Prove (or disprove) that if $a\equiv b\pmod{n+1}$, then the radix-$n$ representation of $a$ and $b$ differ in at least two digits.

Edit to add some more details:

I arose at this conjecture while trying to find a simple way to partition integers into a small number of sets in such a way that no two integers in a set differ by only a single digit. I have only verified for a relatively small number of cases, but it seems to work. It makes some intuitive sense to me for reasons that are tricky to verbalize.

As for an attempt at a proof, my initial thought was to observe that if $a$ and $b$ differ in only a single digit, then $a-b=cn^d$ for some integers $1\leq c<n$ and $d\geq0$. Then, if $a\equiv b\pmod{n+1}$, then $(n+1)\mid cn^d$. But from here I'm stuck.

Comment: Ooh...by the way, do not forget to include your own thoughts and efforts on the question.  Have you worked on starting a proof, or searched for a counterexample?  We need to see such efforts, in your question post, so that we may help lead you to what you may need to finish.  Oh...let me also add, we don't provide answers and proofs on demand.  We ask, however, that you "pay" for help  by showing you've seriously put effort into proving/finding a counter-example.

Comment: @amWhy: My bad. I've added a bit more details, including the basic approach I've tried so far.

Comment: @zappa `then n+1 | cn^d` But $\;\gcd(n+1, n)=1\,$, so $\;\cdots\;$ P.S. Also note that, the way you wrote it, $c$ could also be negative so the right condition is rather $0 \lt |c| \lt n\,$.

Comment: Well, that's a great start.  It always helps, and never hurts, to include such background.  That can be useful for answerers to launch from.

Comment: @dxiv oh crap, now I feel silly. I blame it on a new baby and severe lack of sleep. Thank you! If you finish that proof as an answer I'll accept it; otherwise, I'll do that myself in a little while.

Comment: @zappa No worry, and if you write a good answer I'll +1 it.

Comment: Don't feel silly -- coming up with a new conjecture is tough, and when you've done so, the proof might be easy...for someone other than you. Or for you, but *tomorrow*'s you rather than today's, once you've had a chance to sleep on it. And I should say that I'm not at all a number-theory person, but *I* thought that the conjecture sounded sort of unlikely at first, so you not only came up with a conjecture, but one that surprised at least one person. :)

Comment: @zappa P.S. On a second read, your draft answer and my previous hint only work in the case where digit differences appear at the *same* position. It's not clear from the question, but assuming it's actually asking about differences in the unordered collections of digits, then this approach is not sufficient. Instead, consider for example the [divisibility by 11 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_rules_for_numbers_1.E2.80.9330) in base 10, and its generalization to [arbitrary base n](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52407).

Comment: I indeed meant in the ordered case. I would say that 123 and 124 differ in only a single digit, whereas 123 and 132 differ in two digits (as do 0123 and 1122). I'm exhausted, so I'll write up my proof tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $a>b$. If $a$ and $b$ differ in just one digit, then there must exist integers $c\in[1..n-1]$ and $e\geq0$ such that $a-b=c\,n^e$. Now, since $a\equiv b\bmod{(n+1)}$, it follows that $(n+1)\mid c\,n^e$. But $\gcd(n,n+1)=1$, so (using an easy generalization of [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#Formulations) to arbitrary integers) this can only happen when $(n+1)\mid c$, which is clearly impossible due to the restriction that $c\in[1..n-1]$.

(For the claim that $\gcd(n,n+1)=1$: using the fact that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{N},\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x,y-x)$, it follows immediately that $\gcd(n,n+1)=\gcd(n,1)=1$.)