The symmetry of multiplications with the number 9
Yesterday while I was watching my 8 year old son doing his math-exercises which was multiplications with 9, I noticed this symmetry in the results of multiplying 9 with the range 1 to 10, which I think is very beautiful! Where does this symmetry in 9 comes from, and are there studies on this whether it is a coincident, does such symmetry apply only to 9, etc.?
I would be very grateful if someone could point me to more reads about this. Thank you in advance!

  9      9      9      9      9      9      9      9      9      9
  x1     x2     x3     x4     x5     x6     x7     x8     x9     x10

(0)[9] (1)[8] (2)[7] (3)[6] (4)[5] (5)[4] (6)[3] (7)[2] (8)[1] (9)[0]
|   |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |
|   |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  -----  |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |
|   |   |  |   |  |   |  |   -----------   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |
|   |   |  |   |  |   |  -------------------  |   |  |   |  |   |  |
|   |   |  |   |  |   -------------------------   |  |   |  |   |  |
|   |   |  |   |  ---------------------------------  |   |  |   |  |
|   |   |  |   ---------------------------------------   |  |   |  |
|   |   |  -----------------------------------------------  |   |  |
|   |   -----------------------------------------------------   |  |
|   -------------------------------------------------------------  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------

(0)    (1)    (2)    (3)    (4)    (5)    (6)    (7)    (8)    (9)
   [9]    [8]    [7]    [6]    [5]    [4]    [3]    [2]    [1]    [0]



See: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/65409/1203597

It works in base $b$ with $b-1$.

Adding 9 is the same as adding 10 and subtracting 1. Therefore the tens digit goes up while the units digit goes down. They change at the same speed leading to this pattern.

I just want to say that while the answer is pretty simple, I remember being very struck by this as a young person, and it was some years before I was able to see the reasoning behind it. I'm happy to see someone else going on this journey.

This symmetry will always happen with multiplications of the largest possible digit, i.e., if you are working in base $b$, then multiples of $b-1$ will be
$$0n_{b-1}\\
1n_{b-2}\\
2n_{b-3}\\
\vdots\\
n_{b-3}2\\
n_{b-2}1\\
n_{b-1}0$$
where $n_k$ defines the $k$-th digit in your system.
In other words, in base $8$, multiples of $7$ are
$$07_8=07_{10}\\
16_8=14_{10}\\
25_8=21_{10}\\
34_8=28_{10}\\
43_8=35_{10}\\
52_8=42_{10}\\
61_8=49_{10}\\
70_8=56_{10}$$
