# Task on divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have exams on number theory coming up.And this is something I don´t really understand, how to handle such tasks. Could anyone please explain it to me in a very understandable way (just studying primary school teaching..) Thank you  folks.

If 7/2a +b, then 7/ 100 a +b.

I could transform it to 100a+b=  7l
and                        2a+b= 7k
But how to prove now? Also the task says " after proving the divisibility, show one rule of divisibility for seven. How does this work?
Thank you so much.Looking forward to your answers.
Sophia

Comment: If $7\mid x$, then $7\mid y$ if and only if $7|(y-x)$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328562/divisibility-criteria-for-7-11-13-17-19

Comment: Do you seek to understand only why the above inference is true or, more generally, do you seek to understand the genesis of this inference when devising a test for divisibility by $7$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

If $a|b$ then $a|a.n + b$

**Long Answer**

Known 
$$ 7|2a +b\tag1$$

Need to prove

$$7| 100 a +b$$
$$\Rightarrow 7| (98+2) a +b$$
$$\Rightarrow 7| 98a+2a +b$$
$$\Rightarrow 7| 98a+7|2a +b$$
$$\Rightarrow 7| 7^2.2.a+7|2a +b$$

As $7| 7^2*2a$ and from $(1)$ we have $7|2a +b$

So
$$7| 100 a +b$$

Comment: thank you so much for the answer!!

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy, have to use only that $7|98$ (as $98=49+49$ and $49=7^2$).

The corresponding rule of divisibility is, in an example:
$7\,|\,105 \iff 7\,|\,(2\cdot 1+5)$ or  $7,|\,522 \iff 7\,|(2\cdot 5+22)$, ...

Comment: thank you i can see the prove. but what is that rule pf divisibility? could you please comment on that? thank you!

Comment: The rule helps deciding whether  a given number is divisible by seven or not. For example for $12544$, this can be written as $125\cdot100+44$, by the statement we have that it's divisible by $7$ iff $125\cdot 2+44$ is so, that is, $294$, by the statement again, it reduces to $7\,\overset?|\,(2\cdot 2+94)$, which now happens to hold..

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ 100 a\!+\! b\ =\ 2a\!+\!b\: +\: 7\,(14 a)$

Comment: thank you, but why is it 14a??

Comment: @Sophia Because $\rm\ x=14\:$ solves $\rm 100 = 2 + 7 x.\ $