# Proof if $n$ is divisible by $3$ then the sum of the digits of $n$ are a multiple of $3$

Tags: divisibility

Proof if $n$ is divisible by $3$ then the sum of the digits of $n$ are a multiple of $3$. What is the name of that theorem and who performed that theorem?
I don't understand the proof given here: [How to Prove the divisibility rule for $3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341202/prove-the-following-given-a-positive-integer-n-and-3-midthe-sum-of-the-dig)