# For numbers divisible by three, why is the sum of their digits able to be divided by three?

Tags: divisibility

When you add the digits of any number that is divisible by three, that sum of those digits also appears to be divisible by three *(with no remainder)*.

For example a number *(which I randomly grab from the top of my head)*:

**289752**

whose digits sum to 33 *(2+8+9+7+5+2=33)*

That sum **33** is divisible by three and so is the original number **289752**.

This is not the case when dividing by 2, for example 12 is divisible by two but when its digits are summed *(1+2=3)* you receive 3 which is NOT divisible by 2.

I have yet to be able to find a counter example for this phenomenon of division by 3.

Why does this happen?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341202/how-to-prove-the-divisibility-rule-for-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n=d_0+d_1\times 10+d_2\times 10^2+\cdots d_n\times10^n$ where $d_i$ are the digits. We note that $10\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, and thus $10^k\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, so

$$n\equiv d_0+d_1+\cdots+d_n \pmod{3}$$

So $n\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ iff $d_0+d_1+\cdots+d_n\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$

If you don't know modular stuff, wikipedia has an article I'm sure. Just google it.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\begin{align}N&=a_0+a_1\cdot 10^1+a_2\cdot 10^2+\cdots+a_m\cdot 10^m\\&=a_0+(9a_1+a_1)+(99a_2+a_2)+\cdots +(99\cdots 9a_m+a_m)\\&=(9a_1+99a_2+\cdots+99\cdots 99a_m)+(a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_m)\\&=(\text{a number divisible by $3$})+a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_m\end{align}$$
So, if $N$ is a multiple of $3$, then $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_m$ is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

If we write a positve integer x in the form $x=a_0+10a_1+...+10^na_n$ for positive integers $n,a_0,...,a_n$, we see that $x \equiv a_0+a_1+...+a_n (mod 3)$, since $10^k \equiv 1 (mod 3)$.

Thus it can be seen that $x$ is divisible by 3 if, and only if, the sum of its digits is divisible by 3.