# Better way to prove $4^{351012345} \equiv 5^{543213510}$ mod $231$ is true?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The question is to judge whether $4^{351012345} \equiv 5^{543213510}$ mod $231$ is true. I'm thinking of just directly calculating the exact modulus of both numbers using modular exponentiation but is there a better way to prove the equivalence holds using another method?

Comment: Do you know Euler's theorem?

Comment: Using Euler's theorem is the standard way to proceed once you know that $\varphi(231)=\varphi(3\cdot7\cdot11)=120$.

Comment: I didn't get very far with it, but there were some interesting results by transforming the exponents from base $10$ into the base of the modulus.  This has a very similar effect to modular exponentiation of course.

Comment: Since $231= 3\cdot 7 \cdot 11$, all you need to do is prove the two numbers are congruent modulo each of the primes.  That makes it pretty quick.

Comment: How do you define as "a better way?"  Start with direct calculation, and show us that work.  You need to provide more context.

Comment: As B. Goddard comments, the quick approach it to work separately modulo each of the prime factors (with the help of Fermat's little theorem). Equivalently, we could use the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: The [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of $231$ is lcm$(3-1,7-1,11-1)=30$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to in comments, the prime factorization of $231=3\times7\times11$.

The [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of $231$ is thus lcm$(3-1,7-1,11-1)=30$.

Therefore, we merely have to prove that $4^{15}\equiv5^0=1\bmod231$,

which follows from $4\equiv1\bmod3, 4^3\equiv1\bmod7$, and $4^5\equiv1\bmod11$.

Comment: Unlikely the OP already knows about Carmichael since it is not often presented (early)  in elementary number theory textbooks

Comment: @BillDubuque:  so OP should learn this "better way" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\bmod m=3,7, 11\!:\ 4^{\large 15n}\! = 2^{\large \color{#c00}{30}n}\!\equiv 1\equiv 5^{\large \color{#c00}{30}k}\,$ by $\,\phi(m)\mid \color{#c00}{30}\,$ & [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242). Now apply CRT (or [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242), $ $  i.e. $\,4^{\large 15n}\!- 5^{\large {30}k^{\phantom{|}}}\!$ is divisible by $3,7,11$ so also by their lcm = product = $231$).

Comment: Note: by [casting out 3's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1239420/242) both big exponents are divisible by $3$ since their digit sum is, and via last digits the expt on $4$ is divisible by $5$, and the expt on $5$ by $10$, so the expt on $4$ is divisible by $15$ and the expt on $5$ by $30$, all by trivial mental arithmetic.