# Testing for divisibility by $3$. Is there an alternative to "the sum of digits is divisible by $3$"?

Tags: divisibility

We know that if we add up all the digits and the sum is divisible by $3$, then the whole number is divisible by $3$. My question is:

> Are there any other methods that a number is divisible by 3, or is the sum of digits the only one known?

Is there a possibility that another method exists?

Thanks

Comment: The same idea works for 9.

Comment: Well, you can write the number in base 3 and check if the last digit is a zero or not.

Comment: Haha nice one. I meant more in base 10. Sorry, i wasn't too specific on that.

Comment: The inductive step of casting out threes is $\,a+10b\equiv a+b\pmod{\!3}.\,$ That's as simple as it gets. Why do you seek "another" method, and how do you define "other", i.e. what is your definition of a test being "other" or "different".

Comment: @BillDubuque trying to see if other methods are possible, that can potentially be used with #s. Yes, sum of digits works, but it seems too simple. By ,,other" i mean any patterns, adding/ multiplying of digits in any form.

Comment: Are you familiar with congruences (modular arithmetic)?

Comment: Just learning :).Sorry if my question seems simple/trivial.

Comment: Does the prior comment mean you are *not* familiar with modular arihmetic / congruences? The more context you provide (including your knowlegde level) the more likely you will receive helpful answers.

Comment: You need all the digits to decide whether a number is divisible by $3$, therefore there is no easier rule. A rule needing only the last digits exists if and only if the number of your interest has no prime factors other than $2$ and $5$, for example for $125$, we need only the last three digits.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be the count of the digits $\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ (i.e., $1,4,$ or $7$) and $\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ (i.e., $2,5,$ or $8$) respectively. Then, $x-y$ is divisible by $3$ (or $x \equiv y \pmod 3$) if and only if the original number is.

This is the second condition for the divisor $3$ at the [Wikipedia article on divisibility rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_rules_for_numbers_1%E2%80%9330).

Comment: But that's essentially equivalent to [casting out threes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1239420/242), i.e. reduce the digits mod $3$ then add them. The above simply groups  together the digits $\equiv 1$ (viz., $1,4,7)$ and the digits $\equiv -1$ (viz. $\,2,5 ,8),\,$ i.e. it's just a *rearrangement* of the sum used in casting out threes.

Comment: That's what i meant! @ Geoffrey Tranq. Are there any other for #3?