# law of divisibility on $37$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

how to find and prove law of divisibility on $37$?

Thanks in advance.

**Added**:---- how to prove for$37$ that: Split off the last digit, multiply by 11, and subtract the product from the number that is left. if the result is divisible by 37 then so is the original number.[divisibility criteria for 37](http://www.sonoma.edu/users/w/wilsonst/courses/math_300/fractions/divisibility/default.html#37)

Comment: define law of divisibility

Comment: @clark for example  law of divisibility on 2 is the last digits of number must be even.

Comment: so it should be an easier or faster process than doing the actual division ?

Comment: I guess you mean divisibility criterion, http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/divisibility.shtml

Comment: Hint: $\rm 37\mid 10^3 - 1,\ $ or note $\rm\: mod\ 37\!:\ 100\equiv -11,\:$ and $\rm\:{-11}^{-1}\equiv 10.$

Comment: http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0001/0001012.pdf might be relevant if you are curious about the first few divisibility rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As $$999=37\cdot27$$

So, $10^3\equiv1\pmod{37}\implies 10^{3k}\equiv1\pmod{37}$

So, $\sum_{0\le r\le n}a_i10^i$

$$=(a_0+10a_1+100a_2)+10^3(a_3+10a_4+100a_5)+10^6(a_6+10a_7+100a_8)\cdots$$

$$\equiv (a_0+10a_1+100a_2)+(a_3+10a_4+100a_5)+(a_6+10a_7+100a_8)\cdots\pmod {37}$$

i.e., we can group by $3$ digits and add to test the divisibility by $37$

EDIT: the explanation of the link in the Question

As $11\cdot(10a+b)-1\cdot(11b-a)=111\cdot a$

$(10a+b)$ will be divisible by $111\iff (11b-a)$ is  divisible by $111$

A more general idea can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328562/divisibility-criteria-for-7-11-13-17-19).

Try to find how  $11,1$ are identified as multiplier from the link.

Answer (score 6):

HINT: $37$ divides $999=37\cdot27$, so $37\equiv-1\pmod{1000}$. Now think about the classic divisibility test for $9\equiv-1\pmod{10}$. Imagine writing the number to be tested in base $1000$.

Answer (score 4):

$\rm mod\ 37\!:\ 100^{-1}\!\equiv 10\:$ so $ $ e.g. $\rm\:37\mid  n = 100^2 c + 100 b + a \iff 37\mid 10^2 n \equiv c + 10 b + 10^2 a$

$37\mid \color{#0a0}{54}\color{blue}{39}\!:\quad \color{#0a0}{54}\!+\!10(\color{blue}{39}) \equiv \color{0a0}{17}\!+\!10(\color{blue}2)\equiv 0 $

$\rm\!\begin{eqnarray} 37\mid \color{#0a0}{44}\color{blue}{47}\color{#c00}{40}\!: &&\!\!\color{#0a0}{44}\!+\!10(\color{blue}{47}\!+\!10(\color{#c00}{40}))\\ \equiv && \color{#0a0}7\!+\!10(\color{blue}{10}\!+\!10(\color{#c00}3))\\ \equiv && \color{#0a0}7\!+\!10(3)\equiv 0\end{eqnarray}$

$\rm\!\begin{eqnarray} 37\mid \color{#0a0}{54}\color{blue}{66}\color{#c00}{65}38\!:  &&\color{#0a0}{54}\!+\!10(\color{blue}{66}\!+\!10(\color{#c00}{65}\!+\!10(38))) \\ \equiv && \color{#0a0}{17}\!+\!10(\color{blue}{29}\!+\!10(\color{#c00}{28}\!+\!10)) \\ \equiv && \color{#0a0}{17}\!+\!10(\color{blue}{29}\!+\!10)\\
\equiv &&\color{#0a0}{17}\!+\!10(2)\equiv 0 \end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 1):

Given a number in base 10, say $d_nd_{n-1}\cdots d_0$, calculate $d_0 + 10d_1+26d_2+d_3+10d4+26d_5+\cdots$ (alternating $1$, $10$, and $26$). The resulting number is divisible by 37 if and only if $d_nd_{n-1}\cdots d_0$ is divisible by $37$.