# can't understand a simple divisibility probelm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am reading [this](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/SatoNT.pdf&ei=1RpyUaGoM8SkrQfmuYCIBw&usg=AFQjCNETb_5iD1tAC1o8hC3XkxG6zzuz8Q&sig2=c_jIUllevvHAiWpHr9VMuA&bvm=bv.45512109,d.bmk) book. In the example 1.1 they said to prove this problem.

probelm

Let $x$ and $y$ be integers. Prove that $2x + 3y$ is divisible
by $17$ iff $9x + 5y$ is divisible by $17$

the solution they provided is

$$17 \mid (2x + 3y) \implies  17 \mid [13(2x + 3y)]$$ or $$17 \mid (26x + 39y) \implies 17 \mid (9x + 5y)$$
 and conversely,

$$17 \mid (9x + 5y) \implies 17 \mid [4(9x + 5y)]$$ or
$$ 17 \mid (36x + 20y) \implies 17 \mid (2x + 3y)$$

I can't understand how the concluded this

$$17 \mid (26x + 39y) \implies 17 \mid (9x + 5y)$$
 implication and this

$$17 \mid (36x + 20y) \implies 17 \mid (2x + 3y)$$

the only rule I know is

> if $\;a|b\;$ then $\;a|bk$.

where a,b and k are integers. we can't deduce the above two implication (that is I confused) using this rule isn't it? is there any other point to determine that above two implications are true?

Comment: Split the 26x into 17x + 9x.  Do the same for 39y = 34y+ 5y.

Comment: This site has latex support, and looks like you are aware of it. Please do not use the code formatting for math. If you want to center the math formulae, you can use `$$`. I have edited your answer as an example.

Comment: @Aryabhata: yes. I am novice here. I couldn't cope with right arrow. I will try my best to use latex in next time. sorry for that.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328562/divisibility-criteria-for-7-11-13-17-19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints: $26x=9x+17x$, $39y=5y+17y+17y$

Answer (score 4):

A useful strategy in such problems can be to **eliminate** one of the variables. So multiply $2x+3y$ by $5$, multiply $9x+5y$ by $3$, and subtract. We get
$$5(2x+3y)-3(9x+5y)=-17x.$$
Now suppose that $17$ divides $2x+3y$. Since $17$ also divides $-17x$, it follows that $17$ divides $3(9x+5y)$. But $17$ is relatively prime to $3$, so $17$ divides $9x+5y$.

A very similar argument shows that if $17$ divides $9x+5y$, then $17$ divides $2x+3y$.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the rules
$$
a\mid b\quad\text{and}\quad a\mid c\quad\Rightarrow\quad a\mid(b+c)\quad\text{and}\quad a\mid(b-c)
$$
which should be helpful here.