# How to quickly compute $2014 ^{2015} \pmod{11}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Without using Fermat's Little Theorem, how can I quickly solve $2014 ^{2015} \pmod {11}$?

Comment: Note that $2013$ is divisible by $11$.

Comment: Just note $2014=11\times 183+1$

Comment: I suppose you started by computing $2014^1\pmod{11},$ right? What did you get?

Comment: ${\rm mod}\ 11\!:\ 2014\equiv 4-1+0-2\equiv 1\ \ $

Comment: @bof I did compute 2014^1 (mod 11), and I got 1.  But I am not sure what to do with the 2015 exponent.  Is there a way to simplify 2014^2015?

Comment: @OmarN $\,2014\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2014^n\equiv 1^n\equiv 1\ $ by the [Congruence Power Rule.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\ \ $

Comment: Can you compute $1^{2015}\pmod{11}$?

Comment: 1^2015 (mod 11) = 1.  Does that mean 2014^2015 mod 11 = 1?  Is it really as simple as just doing one number at a time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "doing one number at a time", but it really is that simple. See Bill Dubuque's comments.

Comment: Marios observation above + binomial theorem : every term except the last will be 0 mod 11, and the last is always a number smaller than 11. Then the procedure can be iterated if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental fact about modular arithmetic is that
$$ ab \bmod n = (a\bmod n)(b\bmod n)\bmod n $$
(and the analogous fact for addition). Apply this rule 2014 times to
$$ \underbrace{2014\cdot 2014\cdot 2014 \cdots 2014}_{2015\text{ factors}} $$
(and then 2014 more times in reverse to get rid of the intermediate "$\bmod 11$"s) and you get
$$ 2014^{2015} \bmod 11 = (2014 \bmod 11)^{2015} \bmod 11 = 1^{2015} \bmod 11 = 1 $$

Comment: i.e., as I said, use the [Congruence Power Rule](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), an inductive extension of the [Congruence Power Rule.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

Comment: @Bill: Yes -- but it looked like the OP needed to see a more detailed explanation of why that rule works.

Comment: Indeed! My comment was meant to help the OP connect the dots between our answers.

Comment: @Henning Makholm, I understand your answer and it makes perfect sense.  What if though, we wanted to apply the same logic to $$ 2014^{2015} \bmod 7 = (2014 \bmod 7)^{2015} \bmod 7 = 5^{2015} \bmod 7 = ? $$  How would you find 5^2015 mod 7 without using a calculator?

Comment: @OmarN $5^6 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$, so find $2015 \bmod 6$, which is $5$, and calculate $5^5 \bmod 7$ which is $5^2\cdot5^3 \equiv 4\cdot-1 \equiv \color{red}{3} \bmod 7$.

Comment: This is the part I get lost at.  Where did you get $5^{6}$ from?  I don't understand how we went from $5^{2015}$ to $5^{6}$

Comment: @OmarN [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ (and $6=7-1$). You don't need this in the original question, but for cutting down the exponent when $a \not\equiv 1$, it's very useful.

Comment: I understand now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

This can be computed in a few seconds of mental arithmetic as follows. First we cast out $11$'s to compute $2014\pmod{11}$ as its alternating digit sum:

${\rm mod}\ 11\!:\ \color{#0a0}{10\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{2014}\equiv 2(\color{#0a0}{10})^3\!+\!\color{#0a0}{10}\!+\!4\equiv 2(\color{#0a0}{-1})^3\!\color{#0a0}{-\!1}\!+\!4\equiv\color{#c00} 1\ $ [cast $11$'s - see below]

Therefore $\ \color{#c00}{2014}^n\equiv \color{#c00}1^n\equiv 1\ $ by the [Congruence Power Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

**Remark** $\ $ The first line is a special case of casting out elevens, the analog of casting out nines, i.e. $\, \color{#0a0}{10\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\,f(\color{#0a0}{10})\equiv f(\color{#0a0}{-1}) = $ alternating digit sum, where $\,f(x)\,$ is the decimal radix polynomial, e.g. above $\, f(x) = 2x^3+x+4,\ f(10) = 2014.\,$ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) for further discussion.

Comment: In the second line, can you tell me where all those numbers are coming from? I am not sure where the numbers in the second line come from.

Comment: @OmarN Because $\,\color{#0a0}{10\equiv -1}\,$ we can replace $\,\color{#0a0}{10}\,$ by $\,\color{#0a0}{-1}\,$ whenever it occurs as an argument of a sum or product (by the linked Cogruence Sum and Product Rules).

Answer (score 2):

I like [Bill Dubuque's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1256756/206402), but I definitely didn't use his approach to find $2014 \bmod 11$, just used a discarding version of long division:

$20 \bmod 11 = \color{red}{9} \\
\to \color{red}{9}1 \bmod 11 = \color{green}{3} \\
\to \color{green}{3}4 \bmod 11 = 1$

And then of course $2014^{2015} \equiv 1^{2015} \equiv 1 \bmod 11$.

If $2014$ had been a bigger number, I would probably have used the alternating digits rule for divisibility by $11$, $(0+4)-(2+1) = 1$, because I would have stopped to think before starting the division process :-)

Comment: My way is $\,2014\equiv 4-2+0-1\equiv 1,\,$ which, to me, is simpler, and more general (it is casting out $11$'s - see my remark).

Comment: @BillDubuque - Yes indeed; see my closing thought

Comment: They're both equally quick here for someone who is skilled. I give a general description of the method you use in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165347/242) [Horner form polynomial evaluation]