# Is there a method to calculate large number modulo?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Is there a (number theoretic or algebraic) trick to find a large
>   nunber modulo some number?

Say I have the number $123456789123$ and I want to find its value modulo some other number, say, $17$.

It's not fast for me to find the prime factorisation first. It's also not fast to check how many multiples of $17$ I can "fit" into the large number.

So I was wondering if there is any method out there to do this efficiently.

> I am looking for something like the other "magic trick" where you sum
>   all the digits and take the result $\mod 9$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328562/divisibility-criteria-for-7-11-13-17-19

Comment: Don't even _think_ about factorisation here! Division is much faster.

Answer (score 5):

The best I could come up with is to use 17*6 = 102.
Dividing by 102 goes pretty fast...

```
 123456789123
  214
   105
     367
      618
        691
         792
          783
           69

 and 69 mod 17 = 1
```

### addendum

You can speed things up by trying to eliminate two digits at a time

```
 123456789123
 1224
 ----
   1056
   1020
   ----
     3678
     3672
     ----
        6912
        6834
        ----
          783
          714
          ---
           69

 and 69 mod 17 = 1
```

### for really large numbers

For really large numbers, you can use the fact that 17 | 100,000,001

The procedure is similar to the check for divisibility by 11, except you break the number up into larger chunks.

Starting from the right, split the number up into 8-digit chunks.
So 123456789123 becomes

```
 chunk #         1     2
 chunk    56789123  1234
```

Compute (sum of odd numbered chunks) - (sum of even numbered chunks)

```
56789123 - 1234 = 56787889
```

If the result is negative, add a big enough multiple of 100,000,001 to
make it positive.

This number is congruent to the original number modulo 17.

```
56787889
5610
----
  6878
  6834
  ----
    4489
    4488
   -----
       1
```

and, again, we get 1

Comment: This is a special case of the universal divisibility test (using various chunks sizes), see my answer. Both (well-known) methods were already mentioned in Lab's prior answer.

Answer (score 2):

$10^2\equiv-2\pmod{17}\implies10^4=(10^2)^2\equiv(-2)^2\equiv4;$

$\displaystyle\implies\sum_{r=0}^na_r10^r\equiv(4)^0(a_3a_2a_1a_0)+(4)^1(a_7a_6a_5a_4)++(4)^2(a_{11}a_{10}a_9a_8)+\cdots\pmod{17}$

Again, $10^8\equiv(-2)^4\equiv-1$

$\displaystyle\implies\sum_{r=0}^na_r10^r\equiv(-1)^0(a_7a_6a_5\cdots a_0)+(-1)^1(a_{15}\cdots a_8)+\cdots\pmod{17}$

Comment: Undoubtedly you know this, but in case others are wondering: for any prime $p>2$ we have $10^{(p-1)/2}\equiv\pm1\pmod p$. The sign here depends on whether $10$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ or not. That, in turn, can be easily determined using the law of quadratic reciprocity. This leads to a divisibility rule like the one here in chunks of $(p-1)/2$ digits. In some cases we can do shorter chunks. The best known cases of that are perhaps $p=13$ ($10^3\equiv-1$) and $p=41$ ($10^5\equiv1$).

Comment: This is a special case of the universal divisibility test (using various chunks sizes), see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *is* fast
to divide 17 into that number.

Where you can gain a lot
is when the number
you want to be divide
is a special form
such as $a^n$,
where $n$ is large.
There are ways
(usually involving the
Euler $\phi$ function)
for rapidly computing
$a^n \bmod{b}$
where $n$ is large.

A good start is to remember that
$a^n \bmod{b}
=(a\bmod{b})^n \bmod{b}
$.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. The reason why "magic tricks" work when studying divisibility by $2,3,5,11$ is the fact that we usually write in base $10$. Change the base and they will stop working. In particular, the following trick would work in base $17$: if the last digit of your number is $0$ then the number is divisible by $17$. Of course, in order to check this you would need to write it in base $17$, which is a vicious circle...

Comment: Great, where can I read about the tricks you mention for $2,3,5,11$? (you don't mention $9$...?)

Comment: @learner: I don't know of any book, I know them from elementary school: for $2$, the last digit must be even; for $3$ the sum of the digits must be divisible by $3$; for $4$, the number formed by the last 2 digits must be divisible by $4$; for $5$, the last digit must be $0$ or $5$; for $8$, the number formed by the last 3 digits must be divisible by $8$; for $10$, the last digit must be $0$; for $11$, sum all the digits on odd positions, sum all the digits on even positions and check whether the difference of these 2 numbers is divisible by $11$.

Comment: divisibility rules of 3 is the same for any base as long as base % 3 == 1, i.e. decimal and hex have identical rules

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the [universal divisibility test:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2063944/242) $ $ repeatedly replace leading digit chunks by their remainder mod the divisor as below, using *least magnitude* remainders $\, -8\le r \le 9\,$ to simplify arithmetic $\!\bmod 17\ $  (so *negative* digits occur, denoted $-d,c := 10(-d)+c\equiv 7d+c,\,$ by $10\equiv -7)$
$$\begin{align}
 \!\bmod 17\!:\,\ 10\equiv -7\ \Rightarrow\quad\ \  &\ \color{#0A0}{1\ 2}\,\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ \ \ {\rm by}\,\ \ \ \ \ \ \color{#0a0}{1\:\!2\equiv -5}\\[.1em]
\equiv\, &\ \color{#0A0}{{-5}},\color{#c00} 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ \ \ {\rm by}\,\ \color{#0a0}{{-}5},\color{#c00}3\equiv\  (\,7\,)\,
 \color{#0a0}{5}+\color{#c00}3\,\equiv\,\color{#0af} 4\\[.1em]
\equiv\, &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \color{#0af}4\ 4\ 5\ 6\ \ \ {\rm by}\,\ \ \ \ \ \ \color{#0af}4\:\!4\equiv (-7)4+4\,\equiv\color{#f60}{-7}\\[.1em]
\equiv\, &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \color{#f60}{{-}\!7}, 5\ 6\ \ \ {\rm by}\,\  \color{#f60}{{-}7},5\equiv\,(\,7\,)\, \color{#f60}{7}+5\,\equiv\, 3\\[.2em]
\equiv\, &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3\ 6\ \ \ \:\!\:\!{\rm by}\ \  \ \ \ \ 3\:\! 6\equiv (-7)3+6\,\equiv\, 2\\
\equiv\, &\qquad\qquad\ 2;\ \ {\bf Quicker,}\,\ 2 \,\text{ digits at a time:}\\[.4em]
 \!\bmod 17\!:\,\ 10^2\equiv -2\ \Rightarrow\quad\ \  &\ \color{#0A0}{12\ 3 4}\ 56\ \ \ {\rm by}\,\  \color{#0A0}{12\ 3 4}\equiv\, (-2)\color{#0a0}{\,12+34\equiv 10}\\[.1em]
\equiv\, &\ \ \ \ \ \ \color{#0A0}{{10}}\ \color{#c00}{56}\ \ \ {\rm by}\,\ \color{#0a0}{10}\ \color{#c00}{56}\equiv\  (-2)\,
 \color{#0a0}{10}+\color{#c00}{56}\,\equiv\,\color{#0af}2\\[.2em]
\equiv\, &\qquad\quad\   \color{#0af}2
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

So $\rm\, 123456\equiv 2\pmod{\!17}.\,$ Indeed $\rm\, 123456 = 7262\cdot 17+2.\,$ Continuing this way we can do the entire number in a couple minutes of *mental* arithmetic. Unlike some other divisibility tests that compute only a binary truth value, this method has the advantage of computing the *remainder*. Further, it doesn't require remembering any *special* algorithm or parameters for each modulus.

**Remark** $ $ Lab & Steven's answers are a special case of above (but without mod arithmetic optimizations), i.e. they use chunk sizes of $\,2\,$ and $\,8,\,$ using $\bmod 17\!:\ 10^2\equiv -2,\ 10^8\equiv -1$.

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2119845/242) for another example using negative digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
1111 1111 1111 1111: 11 17 73 101 137 5882353

1   10  |2   15  |3   14  |4   4   |
5   6   |6   9   |7   5   |8   16  |

9   7   |10  2   |11  3   |12  13  |
13  11  |14  8   |15  12  |16  1   |

17  10  |
```

so stack them by every 16 decimal digits, and the mid-point `10^8` congruent to -1 :

```
          123,456,789,123  ( mod 17 )
 ------------------------
 ≡ -1 * 1234 + 56,789,123  ( mod 17 )
 ≡             56,787,889  ( mod 17 )
 ------------------------
```

every 2 digits congruent to `15, aka -2`, and every 4 congruent to `4`, thus

```
 ≡ (     56 <78> [78] 89 ) ( mod 17 )
```

---

```
   (4 * (-2 * (56) + <78>)
 ≡  +   (-2 * [78] + (89)) ( mod 17 )
```

---

```
 ≡ -203 ( mod 17 )
 ≡  -16 ( mod 17 ) => [ 1 ]
```