# Fast Way of Finding The Remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have the following question:

> > Find the remainder of $29\times 2901\times 2017$ divided by $17$

I already have the answer (7) for this problem. I solved it using the long way by multiplying all of the numbers then divvy them with 17. I am just thinking if there are any fast way of solving this. My solution takes a long time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:**

> > If
> >     $$a\equiv b\pmod c$$ And $$d\equiv e\pmod c$$ You can multiply the two to get $$a\times d\equiv b\times e\pmod c$$

Doing this for the numbers separately, then multiplying the expressions will get you the solution very quickly.

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) for this Congruence Product Rule. But here we can also exploit radix rep to mod out chunks of digits, which greatly simplifies the computation - see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can write each number as a multiple of $17$ plus a small remainder:

$$(17+12)(170\cdot 17+11)(118\cdot 17+11).$$

When you multiply this out (which you don't have to do) every term is a
multiple of $17$ except the last one $12\cdot 11\cdot 11$.  So you need
consider only this last product. We can repeat what we just did with a 
little factoring.  The above $= 3\cdot 11 \cdot 4 \cdot 11 = 33\cdot 44
= (17+16)(2\cdot 17 + 10).$  So you need consider only $16\cdot 10$.

Comment: $(-5)\cdot(-6)\cdot(-6)$ is easier to compute.

Comment: @tomasz  Yes, but from the question, I don't think the OP knows about modular arithmetic yet, so dealing with a negative remainder is an extra complication.  Although I see a "mod" answer was accepted as best, so maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5):

> Find remainder after dividing $29 \times 2901 \times 2017$ by $17$.

Work $\mod 17$ !

\begin{align} 
& 29 \times 2901 \times 2017 \\
& 12 \times 1201 \times 317 \\
& 12 \times 1201 \times 147 \\
& 12 \times 351 \times 62 \\
& 12 \times 11 \times 11 \\
& 1452 \\
& 602 \\
& 92 \\
& 7.
\end{align}

Comment: This is much easier if one works with least magnitude reps (i.e. allow negative remainders), e.g. see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in $15$ seconds of *purely mental* modular arithmetic of *small* numbers using the [universal divisibility test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2976824/242), which is essentially the division algorithm ignoring quotients. To obtain optimal speedup we use *least magnitude* remainders,  e.g. $-1$ vs. $16\pmod{\!17}$ since doing so simplifies subsequent arithmetic. To reduce a decimal number mod $n$ we continually mod out the leading chunks of its digits. Since we allow negative remainders, we will encounter negative digits, delimited by a comma, e.g. $\,a,b := a(10)\!+\!b.\,$ We  prove $\ 3247\equiv 0\pmod{\!17}\,$ for practice.

$\begin{align}{\rm mod}\ 17\!:\qquad
        &\,\ \color{#90f}{32}\ 47\\
\equiv\ &{\color{#90f}{-2}},\color{#0a0}47 \ \ \ \text{by }\ \ \ \ \ \,\color{#90f}{32}\,\equiv\,\color{#90f}{-2} \\
\equiv\ &\quad\ \ \, \color{#f84}{\bf 1}7\ \ \ \text{by }\ {\color{#90f}{-2}},\color{#0a0}4 \equiv\, \color{#90f}{{-}2}(10)\!+\!\color{#0a0}4\equiv -16\equiv \color{#f84}{\bf 1} \\[-.3em]
\text{Let's do the number in the OP}\qquad\ \ \ \ \\[-.3em]
        &\,\ \color{#90f}{29}\ 01\\
\equiv\ & {\color{#90f}{-5}},\color{#0a0}01\ \ \text{ by }\quad \color{#90f}{29\,\equiv\, -5} \\
\equiv\ &\quad\ \  \color{#f84}{\bf 1}1\ \ \, \text{ by }\ \color{#90f}{{-}5},\color{#0a0}0\equiv {\color{#90f}{-5}(10)\!+\!\color{#0a0}0}\equiv -50\equiv\color{#f84}{\bf 1}\\
\equiv\ &\quad \,\color{#08f}{-6}\\[-.2em]
\text{Similarly $\,2017\equiv\color{#c00}{-6}\ $ so we have}\phantom{MM}\\[-.2em]
&\ 29\cdot 2901\cdot 2017\\
\equiv\ &(-5)(\color{#08f}{-6})(\color{#c00}{-6})\\
\equiv\ &(-5)\ \color{#08f} 2\\
\equiv\ &\ 7 \end{align}\qquad\qquad$

where we have applied the [Congruence Product and Sum Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) many times above.

**Remark** $ $ I wrote every little detail above to help avoid confusion with negative digits. Once one gains proficiency there is no need to be so extremely verbose. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2976824/242) for a larger example which also employs negative digits for optimization.

Comment: (+1) The OP did say "fast way" of finding the remainder, this is it!

Answer (score 2):

29 × 2901 × 2017 $\equiv$ 12 × 11 × 11 (mod 17)

12 × 121 $\equiv$ (mod 17)

12 × 2 $\equiv$ (mod 17)

24 $\equiv$ 7 (mod 17)

Comment: Even faster if you use negative modulos to keep the numbers small, so in this case, the first line would be $(-5)*(-6)*(-6)$

Comment: Ok I keep in mind that.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh: $ (-a) \equiv (b - a) (\mathrm{mod}\, b)$

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are given in decimal representation, therefore I would start by simplifying $100 \bmod 17$. We have that $20\equiv 3$, therefore $100=20\times 5\equiv 3\times 5 = 15\equiv -2$. This allows us to write:

$$2900\equiv -2\times 29\equiv -2\times (-5) = 10$$

And

$$2000\equiv -2\times 20\equiv-2\times 3 = -6$$

We thus have:

$$29\times 2901\times 2017\equiv -5\times 11\times (-6) = 30\times 11\equiv -4\times 11\equiv -4\times (-6) = 24\equiv 7$$