# Efficient modular reduction of integers in radix representation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

I'm trying to find an easy and fast way to get the result of
$$353094232\bmod721$$
I would solve this by dividing manually the terms until I get the remainder of dividing, but I was wondering if there is a faster way, like breaking down $721$ in $7\cdot103$ and doing something.

I can't find any theorem or property regarding this specific case.

Comment: Long division is pretty easy.  If you want to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, that works too...but I doubt it saves time.

Comment: $353094232 \bmod 721=344$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't think this is a duplicate of the other since we are not aware of the factorization of $353094232$ without first looking for it and there is no guarantee that it is a perfect power.  The question would seem to be about finding a general method regardless of if it is a perfect power or not.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry, this was the wrong link.

Comment: For fast modular computation see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication).

Comment: Long division is seriously the best way to go.

Comment: long division is the way to go.  Fortunately we don't have to keep track of the quotient-- we can just toss out the divisors.  If you are doing this on paper or in your head tossing out $7$s and $103$ will be easier than $721$ but it make take a bit of calculation to convert $a\mod 7$ and $b\mod 103$ to $c\mod 721.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and answers! I will solve with the long division method, then

Comment: Casting out $7$ give you $1\mod 7$ fairly easily.  Casting out $103$ gives you $35 \pmod 103$ with a little bit more but not much trouble.  $103K+35=7M + 1$ can be solved by rewriting $98K + 35 + 5K = 7M + 15$ is solvable with $K=3$ and $M=14K+5$.

Comment: I added a CRT solution by [casting out $103$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) (probably similar to what @fleablood had in mind in the prior comment).

Comment: @BillDubuque  Actually not what I had in mind.  I literally  threw out multipls of $103$ which wasn't hard but certainly wasn't worth writing about. $100 \equiv -3\pmod 103$ would have been a lot easier.

Comment: We can speed up the calculation if we have a power modulo some number. But for a number modulo a number there is no possibility for a speed-up. We just have to compute it with a division with remainder.

Comment: If we want to do it by hand, in the case of a number with small prime factors , as $60$ , it might be an advantage to use the chinese remainder theorem. But in this case, we are reduced to $103$ which has no big effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doable in a minute of mental arithmetic via CRT. $\bmod 103\!:\ 100\equiv -3\Rightarrow p(100)\equiv p(-3)\,$ for any polynomial $\,p(x)\,$ with integer coefs, by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3173344/242) or by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). In particular when we write an integer $\,n\,$ in radix $100$ this this yields $n = p(100)$ as a (radix) polynomial $\, n = p(100) =  d_0 + d_1(100) + d_2(100^2)+\cdots,\,$ whose coef's $d_i$ are its radix $100$ digits. A [handy way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52815/242) to evaluate $\,n = p(100)\equiv p(-3)\,$ is to write the polynomial in "nested" Horner form and evaluate it "inside out" as below - with $\rm\color{#90f}{partial}\ \color{#0a0}{eval}\color{#c00}{uations}$ written below it.

$\!\!\begin{align}
\bmod 103\!:\,\ n = \color{#f6f}3,\color{#0af}{53},09,\color{#0a0}{42},32_{\:\!100} = (((\color{#f6f}3(100)+&\color{#0af}{53)}\,100\,+\,9)\,100\,+\,\color{#0a0}{42})\,100\,+\,32 = p(100)\\[.3em] 
\text{thus, by $\,100\equiv -3,\ $}\,\ n\equiv (((\color{#f6f}3\,({-3}) + &\color{#0af}{53})({-3}) + 9)\color{#90f}{(-3)}+\color{#0a0}{42})(-3) + 32\equiv 35\\
   \text{evaluating from inside-out yields:}\ \ \ \ \ \                                           &44)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \underbrace{\color{#90f}{{-}20)}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  {\color{#c00}{-1}}}_{\large\!\!\!\! \color{#90f}{-20(-3)}\ +\ \color{#0a0}{42}\ \equiv\ \rlap{\color{#c00}{-1}\ }})\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 35)\\
\end{align}$

$\!\bmod 7\!:\ \ \ \ \ \ 353094232\equiv 1\,$ by [this Remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2063944/242) ($10$ secs of mental arithmetic).

$\!\bmod 721\!:\,\ 353094232\equiv 35+103\underbrace{\left[\dfrac{1\!-\!35}{103}\bmod 7\right]}_{\Large\frac{-34}{-2}\equiv\ 17\ \equiv\  3}\equiv 344\ $ by [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242)

Though it is instructive, it is not any quicker than long division. But it may be for other numbers.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2976824/242) for another example of modular Horner poly evaluation notated more concisely, which shows how to simplify calculation using negative digits.