# Proof for divisibilty tests for 13, 16, 17,19

Tags: derivatives, divisibility, real-numbers

I would like to know the divisibility tests for 13, 16, 17, 19. I also would appreciate the proof for the divisibility test done. Please oblige!

Rgds 
Jayanth

Comment: The only useful test is the one for 13 (which also covers 7 and 11): form the alternating sum of blocks of 3 from right to left: 2911272 -> 2-911+272=-637 and 637 is 13 times 49.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328562/divisibility-criteria-for-7-11-13-17-19

Answer (score 0):

Test for divisibility by 13. Add four
times the last digit to the remaining
leading truncated number. If the
result is divisible by 13, then so was
the first number. Apply this rule over
and over again as necessary.
Example: $50661\rightarrow5066+4=5070\rightarrow507+0=507\rightarrow50+28=78$ and $78$ is
$6\times13$, so $50661$ is divisible by $13$.

Test for divisibility by 17. Subtract
five times the last digit from the
remaining leading truncated
number. If the result is divisible by
17, then so was the first number.
Apply this rule over and over again
as necessary.
Example: $3978\rightarrow397-5\times8=357\rightarrow35-5\times7=0.$ So $3978$ is divisible by $17$.

Test for divisibility by 19. Add two
times the last digit to the remaining
leading truncated number. If the
result is divisible by 19, then so was
the first number. Apply this rule over
and over again as necessary.
EG: $101156\rightarrow 10115+2\times6=10127\rightarrow1012+2\times7=1026\rightarrow102+2\times6=114$ and
$114=6\times19$, so $101156$ is divisible by 19.

NOTE: I found it from some blog.

Comment: Some error with the math

Comment: Last paragraph.

Comment: I mean syntax for latex