# Why does casting out $9$ and $11$ work to compute remainders?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

I found two examples that I'd like to understand:

**Example 1:** Find $112358132134 \mod 9$.

*Solution is:*
$1+1+2+3+5+8+1+3+2+1+3+4 \mod 9 = 7 \mod 9 = 7$

**Example 2:** Find $62831853 \mod 11$.

*Solution is:*
$(-6)+2+(-8)+3+(-1)+8+(-5)+3 \mod 11 = -4 \mod 11 = 7$

My question is: Based on what property we sum the digits of the number ( as Example 1) or subtract (as Example 2)?

Comment: Lookup [divisibility rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_rules_for_numbers_1.E2.80.9330).

Comment: $10\equiv 1\pmod{9}$, so since $112358132134 = 4 + 3\cdot 10 + 10^2 + 2\cdot 10^3 + ...$, it follows that $112358132134$ mod $9$ is the sum of the digits. Similarly, $10\equiv -1\pmod{11}$, so you get a factor of $-1$ every time you have an odd power of $10$ coming from the decimal expansion.

Comment: Those are specific to the number 9.  And the number 11.  9=10 - 1.  And 11 =10+1.

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328562/divisibility-criteria-for-7-11-13-17-19

Answer (score 4):

Usually, we cannot compute the remainder of a number mod $n$ by summing the digits (example 1), *or* by subtracting alternately (example 2). This is a special trick that works for mod $9$ and $11$. It also works for mod $3$.

- To compute the remainder of a number mod $3$ or mod $9$, you may **sum the digits** and then compute the remainder of that result.

  **Why it works:** we write numbers in base $10$, and $10 \equiv 1$ mod $3$ or mod $9$, so multiplying by $10$ is really multiplying by $1$.
- To compute the remainder of a number mod $11$, you may **alternately add and subtract the digits** and then compute the remainder of that result.

  **Why it works:** we write numbers in base $10$, and $10 \equiv -1$ mod $11$, so multiplying by $10$ is really multiplying by $-1$ (changing the sign).

You can read more about these divisibility rules and others at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$1\bmod9=10\bmod9=100\bmod9=1000\bmod9=\cdots 1,$$
$$1\bmod11=100\bmod11=\cdots 1,$$
$$10\bmod11=1000\bmod11=\cdots-1.$$

See the decimal expansion as a linear combination.

Answer (score 1):

Radix notation has $\color{#c00}P\!$$\textit{olynomial form}$ $\, n = \color{#c00}{P}(10) = d_k 10^k +\cdots + d_2\cdot 10^2 + d_1\cdot 10 + d_0\, $

so $\, {\rm mod}\ 9\!:\, \color{#0a0}{10\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, P(\color{#0a0}{10})\,\equiv\, P(\color{#0a0}1)\,\equiv\, d_k+\cdots + d_1 + d_0 = $ sum of digits $\,d_i,\ $ and

$ {\rm mod}\ 11\!:\, \color{#90f}{10\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, P(\color{#90f}{10})\equiv P(\color{#90f}{-1})\equiv (-1)^k d_k+\cdots - d_1 + d_0 = $ alternating digit sum.

In both cases we employed the  the $ $ [Polynomial Congruence Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $ $ i.e. $\,a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\,P(a)\equiv P(b),\ $ for any *polynomial* $\,P(x)\,$ with *integer* coefficients, and any integers $\,a,b.$

---

**Remark** $\ $ These tests are special cases $\,(x = 10)\,$ of results true for any polynomial, namely

$ {\rm mod}\ x\!-\!1\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{x\ \equiv\ 1}\ \Rightarrow\  P(\color{#0a0}{x})\,\equiv\, P(\color{#0a0}1)\,\equiv\, d_k+\cdots + d_1 + d_0 = $ sum of coef's $\,d_i,\ $ and

$ {\rm mod}\ x\!+\!1\!:\,\ \color{#90f}{x\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, P(\color{#90f}{x})\equiv P(\color{#90f}{-1})\equiv (-1)^k d_k+\cdots - d_1 + d_0 = $ alternating coef sum.

Thus if the coef sum $\,P(1) = 0\,$ then $\,P(x)\equiv P(1)\equiv 0\,\pmod{x\!-\!1}\,\ $ so $\,\ x\!-\!1\mid P(x),$

and, similarly, if  $\ P(-1) = 0\,$ then $\,P(x)\equiv P(-1)\equiv 0\pmod{x\!+\!1}\,\ $ so $\,\ x\!+\!1\mid P(x).$

Both are special case of the well-known $ $ **Factor Theorem** $\,\ x\!-\!a\,\mid\, P(x)-P(a).$

In particular, for $\,x = b = \,$ radix, we get the base $b$ analog of casting out $9$ and $11$ in radix $10$

Answer (score 0):

**Remainder after division by $11$**

The OP's question asked for the properties that 'force' the technique. They should be aware that there are often several ways to tackle math problems.

Working in $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ with numbers presented in their base ten representation.

Problem: For any $m$ find the remainder $r$ after division by $11$: $\;m = 11q + r$.

Without using [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) and negative numbers, you can employ *symbolic homotopy rules* to transform $m$ down to $r$. Since this is recreational math, we leave it to the reader to formalize these rules; here we only give some examples.

This method is useful for an organized approach where you can carefully check each step for errors.

Example 1: If $m \lt 11$ then $m \sim [m]$

Example 2: $20]. \sim [9]$

Example 3: $30]. \sim [8]$

Example 4: $90]. \sim [2]$

Example 5: $55] \sim [0]$

Example 6: $58] \sim [3]$

Example 7: $85] \sim 30]. \sim [8]$

Example 8: Find the remainder $r$ for $\frac{62831853}{11}$:

$\quad 62]831853 \sim 408]31853 \sim 12]31853 \sim 13]1853 \sim 21]853 \sim 108]53 \sim 95]3 \sim 403] \sim [7]$

Example 9: $29]0 \sim 70]. \sim [4]$

Example 10: $100]0000 \sim 100]00] \sim 100] \sim [1]$

Example 11: $11]11111 \sim 11]111 \sim 11]1 \sim [1]$