# A divisibility rule for 7 in primoradic with an historical example. I'm looking for other examples of the same type.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, math-history, primorial

I have given as much information as I could about primoradic [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4140740/definition-of-the-lineage-of-an-integer-is-it-well-defined).

In primoradic , multiples of 7 which are not multiples of 2, 3 or 5 end
by (...:0:1:0:1), (...:1:3:0:1), (...:2:2:2:1), (...:3:0:0:1), (...:3:4:2:1), (...:4:2:0:1), (...:5:1:2:1) or (...:6:3:2:1).
Let us apply that to an historical example. Consider a number studied by Blaise Pascal, N=287.542.178. Let $N1=N/2=143.771.089$. In primoradic, $$N1=(14:15:10:7:6:1:3:0:1)\equiv49 \pmod {210}$$ It was sufficient to have $(...:1:3:0:1)$ to know that Pascal's number is divisible by 7. By generalization, you have a divisibility rule for any prime number. For $p_{n+1}$, you have $Card((Z/p_n\#)^\times)$ endings. For example, for $11$, $(...:7:3:2:0:1)$ is one of the $48$ endings.

Notice : $$N1=(14:15:10:7:6:1:3:0:1)=1+3 \times6+1\times{30}+6\times{210}+7\times{2310}+10\times30030+15\times510510+14\times9699690$$
To ask a **precise question** : you could find a number like Blaise Pascal's one, which is a multiple of $7$ and write it in primoradic. Or a multiple of any prime number as 107 ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134410/is-ulam1-prime))

Comment: $\begin{align}
\bmod 7\!:\ &d_0 + 2d_1 +6d_2 + 30d_3 + 210 n\\
\equiv\ \        & d_0 + 2d_1 -\,\  d_2 +\,\ 2 d_3
\end{align}\quad$

Comment: It parametrizes the solutions: $ $  if $n$ is odd $(\!\!\iff\! d_0 = 1)$ then $\,7\mid n\!\iff\! d_2\equiv 1 + 2(d_1 + d_3)\pmod{\!7},\,$ which is true for *any* integers $\,d_1,d_2,d_3,\,$ not only those in the restricted digit range.

Comment: Yes, it works for all odd $n$ (I edited it before you replied). Beware the notation clash (the $n$ in $210n$ is not meant to be the same).

Comment: Click on "Help" in the comment editor, or "Advanced help" in the answer editor.