# Problems With Divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

While surfing on the internet I found a divisibility rule for 7

> Subtract 14 times the last digit from remaining truncated number. Repeat the step as necessary. If the result is divisible by 47, the original number is also divisible by 47. This too is difficult to operate for people who are not comfortable with table of 14.

I was thinking if we could prove it .Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you please elaborate.I am not able to understand what do you mean?

Comment: I have written that a number is divisible by 47 if the last number(2-digit or 3-digit) at the end is divisible by 47

Comment: After the process

Comment: [A divisibility rule for 47](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/divisibility-rule-7-13-17-19-23-29-31-37-41-43-47/), right? Also see [here for a proof](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0001012.pdf).

Comment: No problem, sir..

Comment: Hey,I am just 13 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $47\cdot3-140=1$

$$47\cdot3a-14(10a+b)=a-14b$$

$$47|(10a+b)\iff47\mid(a-14b)$$

**See also** : [Divisibility criteria for $7,11,13,17,19$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328562/divisibility-criteria-for-7-11-13-17-19/328576#328576)

Comment: As $330-47\cdot7=1,$  $$33(10a+b)-329a=33b+a$$