# Question on Modular Arithmetic proof

Tags: modular-arithmetic

From my textbook

I am really confused. The only numbers this works for are multiples of 10, and 11.

10 mod 3 is 1, yes, but 12 mod 3 is 0!

Any idea on how to answer this question? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: It is a special case of [Casting out nines.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242)  Note $\,n\equiv k\pmod 9\,\Rightarrow\, n\equiv k\pmod 3\,$ by $\,3\mid 9\mid n-k\ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes $12\equiv 0\pmod 3$ and so is $1+2$ the sum of the digits of twelve.  Suppose
$$n=\sum_{k=0}^m a_k10^k,\quad 0\le a_k\le 9\text{ for }1\le k\le m$$.

Since $10^k\equiv 1\pmod 3$ for any $k$, 
$$n\equiv\sum_{k=1}^ma_k\pmod 3.$$

Comment: Oh I see I just interpreted the question wrong thank you