# Trying to determine the relationship of m and n in a Casting Out m under base n

Tags: modular-arithmetic, computational-complexity, solution-verification

While exploring $\mathbb{Z/n}$ I stumbled upon [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines)

It explains that Casting Out Nines works because our common counting system is decimal and thus there exist a congruence relation as follows

$$10\equiv 1 \pmod{9}$$

which result in the remainder of the sum to become the sum of remainders

I was then curious on what the general case look like for any positive integer base n,

that is, how is n related to the modulus m in a "Casting Out m" system in base n.

Putting the above question in the context of base 10, I suspect I need to solve for m in the following equations given a known n (noting $n^0=1$)

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
n\equiv 1 \pmod{m}
\\
n^{k}\equiv n^{k-1} \pmod{m}, k \in \mathbb{Z},k>1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

To get some idea on what the solution may look like I consider the following simpler case

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
n\equiv 1 \pmod{m}
\\
n^2\equiv n \pmod{m}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Since this is a nonlinear congruence relation, I use [Method of Successive Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_successive_substitution) to approach it

Rewriting 1st congruence equation as
$$n=1+ym,y\in \mathbb{Z}$$
Plug this into the 2nd equation while also rewriting the LHS
$$1+ym=(ym+n)^2$$
$$1+ym=y^2m^2+2ymn+n^2$$
$$y^2m^2+y(2mn-1)+(n^2-1)=0$$
y can then be solved with the quadratic formula, with the constraint that y must be $\in \mathbb{Z}$
y can then be rewritten as
$$y'=y+mu,u \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Substituting this back to the 1st equation we found our n as
$$n=1+(y+mu)m$$
$$(1-n)+ym+m^2u=0$$
Therefore our m is related with our n by a quadratic equation

> 1. Any assumptions or overlooked concepts in my approach to explore this problem?
> 2. The computation seems getting more complicated as you increase k towards infinity (expected because nonlinear congruence systems are NP hard according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Computational%20complexity)). **How to check whether the solution to this problem always converges to some value** for any positive integers n, that is,
>
> is Casting out m always possible for any positive integer bases n?

Comment: I think you're doing much more work than necessary here: it is not hard to show that equivalence modulo $m$ is a [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation), from which it follows immediately that if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, then $n^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Well, $n\equiv1$ implies $n^2\equiv n$. It is always the case (for bases 3 or higher) that in base $n$ you can cast out $(n-1)$s. For example, in octal, $721$ is written $1321_8$, and $1+3+2+1=7$. You may also want to look up "casting out elevens".

Comment: I see
After using your advice to redo the problem without the extra work, I got $$(n-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$$ which is the same as saying that m=n-1 by the definition of residue class

However putting n=2 and the equation still holds, including the $$n^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$$, except I am not sure if m=1 actually make sense since in $\mathbb{Z/1}$ there's only one element in the residue class, 0. I guess that's why casting out m fails for binary base?

Comment: Taking the residue class modulo $1$ makes sense because it is well defined, but it is trivial because every number is in the same class. In this sense, casting out $1$ doesn't fail in base $2$, it is simply useless: recursively summing the digits of a binary number always gives you $1$.

Comment: Unless that number is $0$, of course...

Comment: I discuss the modular view of casting out nines and generalizations in many posts here, e.g. [this one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242)