# The sum of digits of $3(3x+3)$ is always $9$ for any $x$ between $1$ and $9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, puzzle, wolfram-alpha

Given the following 'joke' I stumbled across today

> This calculation will tell you who you really are:
>
> - Pick any number between 1 to 9.
> - Now multiply it with 3.
> - Add 3.
> - Now again multiply it with 3.
> - You will get 2 digits, now add them.
>
> Now this number will tell you what you really are...

The rest is not really relevant, but it's easy enough to figure out that the answer is always `9`. However when I tried to 'prove' this for friends in an easy manner I stumbled upon two problems.

First of all I had to add the different parts, which I wasn't able to do with 'simple' maths, so I used $\lfloor \frac{x}{10} \rfloor + x \mod 10$. Due to the jump in mathematical functions I had no idea how to continue with 'pure mathematics' so I wanted to get WolframAlpha to simply do the work for me and spit out the number 9, but I wasn't able to get it to work only within $1\leq x \leq 9,\ x \in \mathbb{Z} $.

Either way, practically speaking I have

$\lfloor \frac{(x \times 3 + 3) \times 3}{10} \rfloor + ((x \times 3 + 3) \times 3 \mod 10)\ \ \ where\ 1\leq x \leq 9,\ x \in \mathbb{Z}$

How would one solve this, either using normal mathematics or how to get this inputted in WolframAlpha in a way it will be understood ([here is the WA link without the restriction on $x$](http://%5Clfloor%20%5Cfrac%7B(x%20%5Ctimes%203%20+%203)%20%5Ctimes%203%7D%7B10%7D%20%5Crfloor))?

Comment: $9$ divides a number, iff it divides the digital root of the number.

Comment: It's clearly divisibly by $9$ so this is an immediate consequence of **casting out nines** (see the linked dupe).

Answer (score 9):

You can show them that they are adding the digits of multiples of $9$ between $18$ and $90$ and then just list them.

$18 \implies 1+8=9$

$27\implies 2+7=9$

$36\implies 3+6=9$

$45\implies 4+5=9$

$54\implies 5+4=9$

$63\implies 6+3=9$

$72\implies 7+2=9$

$81\implies 8+1=9$

$90\implies 9+0=9$

While this approach is not sophisticated, it might be fit-for-purpose when discussing with those who are not mathematically inclined.

Comment: It definitely makes the brute force approach far more comprehensible, though it definitely feels quite... ungeneric.

Comment: @DavidMulder Well, for those less mathematically inclined, sometimes a more general approach doesn't connect.  We are therefore left with keeping things simple and more specific.

Comment: Yeah, definitely true, I guess I was chasing two different birds and trying to hit them with the same stone: Not gonna work.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 8):

For any integer $k$, $3(3k+3)=9(k+1)$ is a multiple of $9$, and one can prove that such a number has digital root $9$.

Comment: This was I guess the answer I was looking for, even if it helps me less in communicating it. In the end this is the same thing as taking a good look at the puzzle and just seeing that the answer is always 9. I guess it's just the programmer in me that wishes to have a model like that, and then running the calculations till I get the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @David See [casting out nines](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) for the arithmetical essence of the matter.

Comment: @DavidMulder Since you wrote $\mod{10}$ I suppose that you are familiar with modular arithmetic. Given a natural number $n$ and the fact that $10 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$ you can prove (in a fairly straightforward way) that $n$ is congruent to the sum of its digits, modulo $9$. Since here $n = 9(x+1)$ has two digits it doesn't take much to spell the proof out for your friends that don't know about modular arithmetic.