# Prove $\left[x \operatorname{mod} 2^w+ x \operatorname{div} 2^w\right] \operatorname{mod} (2^w -1) = x \operatorname{mod}(2^w -1)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Been trying to prove different versions of something similar for so long now. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: x and w are integers.

$\left[x \operatorname{mod} 2^w+ x \operatorname{div} 2^w\right] \operatorname{mod} (2^w -1) = x \operatorname{mod}(2^w -1)$

Maybe I'm unclear but $\operatorname{div}$ is integer division which is not equivalent with $\div$ which is floating point division, and $\operatorname{mod}$ is modulo.

Comment: What does x div 2^w mean?

Comment: Is your equation modulo $2^w$ or $2^{w}-1$ ? Or are you choosing representative from these fields ? What do you mean by $ x div 2^w$ ... explain your problem a little more & we will help.

Answer (score 3):

Let just write $x=2^wq+r$ with $q\in\mathbb Z$ and $r\in\{0,1,2,..,2^w-1\}$ where $q$ and $r$ are simply the quotient and remainder in Euclidian division.

$\begin{array}{ll}
x \pmod{2^w}=r & \mathrm{definition}\\
x\ \operatorname{div}\ 2^w = q & \mathrm{definition}\\
x = 2^wq+r+(q-q)=(2^w-1)q+(q+r)\Rightarrow x\equiv q+r\pmod{(2^w-1)} & \mathrm{insane\ trick}\\
\end{array}$

So yes $q+r\pmod{(2^w-1)}\equiv x\pmod{2^w-1}$, I did nothing that fancy but explicitely writing definitions.

Comment: Awesome! Could explain the "insane trick" a bit more like why do you have (q - q) ?

Comment: well, I added zero.

Comment: @Zac The "insane trick" is the analog of casting casting out nines for radix $2^w,\,$ see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a radix $\,\color{#c00}n = 2^w$ analog of (partially) [casting out nines](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242), which computes the remainder modulo  $9\, (= $ radix $\!-\!1)$  by summing the decimal digits. Let's make the analogy clear:

${\rm mod}\ 9\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{10\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow 123 = 12\cdot \color{#c00}{10} + 3\equiv 12+3 \equiv 123\!\div\! 10 + 123\bmod 10$

${\rm mod}\ n\!-1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{n\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,x =\!\!\!\!\underbrace{ q\cdot \color{#c00}{n}\ +\ r}_{\rm division\ algorithm}\!\!\!\!\! \equiv q\ +\ r\,\equiv\ \underbrace{x\div n}_{\large q}\ +\ \underbrace{x\bmod n}_{\large r} $

Yours is just the prior for radix $\, n = 2^w$