# Prove the divisibility test by $7,11,13$ for numbers more than six digits

Tags: divisibility

Prove the divisibility test by $7,11,13$ for numbers more than six digits

---

**Attempt:**

We know that $7\cdot 11 \cdot 13 = 1001$. The for a six-digit number, for example, $120544$, we write it as
$$ 120544 = 120120 + 424 = 120\cdot1001 + 424 $$
thus we just check the divisibility of $424$ by $7,11,13$.

Know for a number with more than six digits,  for example: $270060340$,

$$270060340 = 270270270 - 209930$$
$$ = 270 \cdot (1001001) - 209930 $$
$$ = 270 \cdot (1001000) + (270 - 209930) =270 \cdot (1001000) - 209660$$

so we check the divisibility of $209660 = 209209 + 451$, or just $451$.

But the test states that: for $270060340$, we group three digits from the right:
$$ 270, 60, 340$$
then check divisibility of $340+270 - (60)$.

How to prove this?

Comment: Essentially, the test uses the fact that $a \equiv (a\mod 1000 - \lfloor a/1000\rfloor)\pmod {1001}$. Just iterate the $\lfloor a/1000\rfloor$ piece of this and note that the sign changes every time you do.

Comment: $a_0+1000a_1+1000000a_2+1000000000a_3+\dots+10^{3n}a_n\equiv a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+\dots+(-1)^n a_n\mod1001$

Answer (score 1):

It's a [radix$+1$ divisibility test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) for radix $10^3,\,$ i.e. the analog of *casting out* $11's$ in radix $10,\,$ viz.

$\!\!\!\begin{align}\bmod 10^{\large 3}\!+\!1\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{10^{\large 3}}\equiv \color{#c00}{\bf -1}\, \ \Rightarrow\!\!\!\!  &\ \ \ \ \ \ \overbrace{d_0 + d_1 \ \color{#0a0}{10^{\large 3}} +\, d_2(\color{#0a0}{10^{\large 3}})^{\large 2}\! + d_3(\color{#0a0}{10^{\large 3}})^{\large 3}+\,\cdots }^{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\textstyle\text{integer in radix $\color{#0a0}{10^{\large 3}}$ with digits $\,d_i$}} \\[.3em] 
&\equiv\, d_0\!+d_1(\color{#c00}{\bf -1})\!+d_2(\color{#c00}{\bf -1})^{\large 2}\! + d_3(\color{#c00}{\bf -1})^{\large 3} +\,\cdots \\[.3em]
&\equiv\, d_0\  \ \color{#c00}{\bf -}\ \  d_1\ \  +\ \  d_2\ \  \color{#c00}{\bf -}\ \  d_3\ +\, \cdots\\[.2em] 
&\equiv\, \color{#c00}{\text {alternating}}\text{ digit sum}\end{align}$

where above mod arithmetic uses [Congruence Sum & Product Rules (or Polynomial Rule)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), and where we use the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242) to compute $\,n\bmod 7\,$ by first reducing $\,n\,$ mod the simpler multiple $1001$ of $7$ (which is "simpler" because it enables the above easy mod arithmetic).

$\!\begin{align}\text{E.g. in your 2nd example: }\ \ \ \ \ \ \ &\overbrace{270\,,\,060\,,\,340}^{\textstyle d_2,\ \ d_1,\ \ d_0}\\[.2em] 
\equiv\ &270\! -\! 060\! +\! 340\, \equiv\, 550\!\pmod{\!1001}\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

$1001$ divides $999,999$ and $999,999 = 1,000,000 - 1$

$270,060,340 = (270,000,000 - 27) + (60,000 + 60) + 340 + 27 -60$

The first two terms are divisible by $1001$ (and hence 7,11, and 13)

Answer (score 0):

For 9-digit number: $abcdefghi$,

$$ abcdefghi = abc000000 + defghi = abc000000 + def \cdot 1001 - def +  ghi $$
so we check divisibility of 
$$ abc000000 - def + ghi = abc \cdot 1001000 - abc000 - def + ghi$$
so we cehck divisibility of 
$$ -abc000 - def + ghi = -(abc \cdot 1001 - abc) - def + ghi$$
in the end we only check $abc + ghi - def$.

If 12-digit number:
$$ a_{1} a_{2} ... a_{11}a_{12} = a_{1} a_{2} a_{3} 000000000 + \underbrace{a_{4} ... a_{12}}_{9-digit}$$

so we check the divisibility of 
$$ a_{1} a_{2} a_{3} 000000000 + ( a_{10}a_{11}a_{12} + a_{4} a_{5}a_{6} - a_{7}a_{8}a_{9})  $$
or just 
$$ = (a_{10}a_{11}a_{12} + a_{4} a_{5}a_{6} - a_{7}a_{8}a_{9} - a{1} a_{2} a_{3}) $$