# n is odd iﬀ 1 appears an odd number of times in the base 3 expansion of n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I know that 1 times 3 to any power is odd number. And 0 or 2 times 3 to any power is even. So, the occurrences of 1s determine if the base 3 expansion of n is odd or even and 1 has to appear odd number of times because 2(2n+1) = 2k which is even. 
But I am having hard time translating these to mathematical statements as I am very new to mathematics.

Comment: To be honest, I understand your argument perfectly even if you did not use any mathematical notation. I believe using mathematical notation would do more harm than good - would make the argument *less* clear.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand your reference to $2n+1$.

Comment: @Yves odd values can pair up is basically what it means, this can actually be used to restate Collatz.$$C(n_3)=\begin{cases}n_31_3\quad\text{if $n_3$ has an odd number of 1s}\\{n_3\over 2}\quad\text{if $n_3$ has an even number of 1s}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: good to know, but the $2n+1$ in the OP has nothing to do there AFAIK.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes it does as $2(2n+1)$ is a digit sum of the odd digits.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: not at all. $2n+1>n$ cannot equal any sum of digits.

Comment: okay misuse of variables in the OP is my best explanation. but you can tell that $1201202022010020101201020101_3$ is even just by the number of ones having an even sum.

Answer (score 4):

With $d_k$ denoting the $k^{th}$ digit of $n$ from the right,

$$n=\sum_{k=0}^m d_k3^k$$
$$=\sum_{k=0,\\d_k=0}^m d_k3^k+\sum_{k=0,\\d_k=1}^m d_k3^k+\sum_{k=0,\\d_k=2}^m d_k3^k$$
$$=\sum_{k=0,\\d_k=1}^m 3^k+2\sum_{k=0,\\d_k=2}^m 3^k$$
$$\equiv\sum_{k=0,\\d_k=1}^m 1 \bmod 2$$ because $3^k\equiv 1\bmod2$.

Hence the number of ones must be odd.

---

**In common language:**

All even digits (zero or two) bring an even contribution, and all odd digits (one) an odd contribution (some power of three). The global parity is the parity of the number of odd contributions.

Answer (score 3):

Don't mistake the lack of formulas for a lack of mathematics. Your proof is more than mathematical enough the way it is.

That being said, it could be *clearer*, even without any formulas. Just a little trim will help (as Yves notes above, the 2n+1 thing is a bit unclear). Something like this is maybe just as good:

> 1 times 3 to any power is odd number. And 0 or 2 times 3 to any power is even. So, the occurrences of 1s determine if the base 3 expansion of n is odd or even.

If you really want to explain more, I would encourage you to explain why 0 or 1 or 2 times a power of 3 is relevant, by referencing the fact that that's what the base 3 expansion of a number is. Also, it could help to frame this proof, so that we all know what's being proven and that it has been proven as we read it:

> Take some number $n$ written in base $3$. The digits (trits) of $n$ denote how $n$ is written as a sum of powers of $3$, some multiplied by $0$, some by $1$ and the rest by $2$. $1$ times any power of $3$ is an odd number. And $0$ or $2$ times any power of $3$ is even. So, the occurrences of $1$s is what determines if $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: "ismroe thn" in the first part @Arthur

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Thakns. Ifiexd ti.

Comment: trits is the common name for base 3 digits by the way. @Arthur

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Of course. It's not like bits are called bigits. I should've known.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_system_topics

Answer (score 0):

It follows by *casting out twos* - the radix $3$ analog of [casting out nines](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) in radix $10,\,$ viz.

$\!\!\!\begin{align}\bmod 2\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{3}\equiv \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\, \ \Rightarrow\!\!\!\!  &\ \ \ \ \ \ \overbrace{d_0 + d_1 \ \color{#0a0}{3}\, +\, d_2\, \color{#0a0}{3}^2 + d_3\,\color{#0a0}{3}^3+\,\cdots }^{\!\!\!\textstyle\text{integer in radix $\color{#0a0}{\,3\,}$ with digits $\,d_i$}} \\[.3em] 
&\equiv\, d_0+d_1\,\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\ +d_2\,\color{#c00}{\bf 1}^2\! + d_3\,\color{#c00}{\bf 1}^3 +\,\cdots \\[.3em]
&\equiv\, d_0  +  d_1\  +\  d_2\  +\  d_3\ +\, \cdots\, \equiv\, \text{ digit sum}\\[.3em]
&\equiv\ \text{number of } \textit{odd }\text{ digits $\,d_i = 1,\, $ by even digits $\equiv 0$} \end{align}$

where we employed the [Congruence Sum & Product Rules (or Polynomial Rule)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)