# is someone having an idea on how "casting out twos" are been done.

Tags: arithmetic

Is someone having an idea on how  "casting out twos" are been done? I know about  "casting out nines" but I try to research for  "casting out twos" and saw nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider base $3$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436595/