# Question with modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was given this question

> A store sold $72$ decks of cards for $\$a67.9b$, where $a$ and $b$ are digits.
> Find $a + b$.

I'm not really sure how to solve this. I tried $100a + 67.9 + b \cdot0.01 \equiv 0 \pmod{72}$. From there you can get $100a + b \cdot 0.01 \equiv 4.1 \pmod{79}$. But this can't work. $b$ is maximum $9$, so you'll always end up with something in the hundreds place when you've divided. What am I supposed to do to solve?

Comment: $\!\begin{align} &\bmod 8\!:\  0 \equiv a679b \equiv790+b \equiv 6+b\Rightarrow b\equiv 2\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{b = 2},\,\ \text{by }\,\ 0\le b\le 9\\
&\bmod 9\!:\ 0 \equiv a679b \equiv a\!+\!6\!+\!7\!+\!9\!+\!b\equiv a\!+\!\color{#c00}b\!+4 \equiv a\!+\!6\Rightarrow a\equiv 3\Rightarrow a=3\end{align}\ \ $

Comment: We used [casting out nines](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) in the prior line, and in the first line we used that $\,\color{#c00}{8\mid 1000},\,$ by $\,2\mid 10\Rightarrow 2^3\mid 10^3,\,$ so $\bmod \color{#c00}8\!: a6(\color{#c00}{1000})+79b\equiv 79b\ \ $