# Divisibility by 13 of a large number written in base 14

Tags: divisibility

I was given this question: suppose 123456789abcd is written in base 14. What is its remainder when divided by 13? I know the answer is zero but I had to do it using Wolframalpha. I'm wondering if there's a smart way to do it, instead of doing it by hand?

Comment: the same method as divisibility by $9$  when written in base $10,$  because $14 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$

Comment: What's this method? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Sum its digits mod $14$ to get the remainder.

Comment: As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) in the dupe, this is the radix $14$ analog of casting out nines, by $14\equiv 1\pmod{13}.\ \ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number $$a_n B^n + a_{n-1} B^{n-1} + ... + a_0 B^0$$
and the number  $$a_n + a_{n-1} + ... + a_0$$
have the same remainder when dividing by $B-1$. The reason is that the difference between these two numbers is
$$a_n(B^n - 1) + a_{n-1}(B^{n-1} - 1) + ... a_0( B^0 - 1)$$
and each $B^k - 1$ is divisible by $B - 1$ since $x - 1$ divides the polynomial $x^k - 1$.

Use $B = 14$ in the case at hand; the remainder when dividing by $13$ will be the same as the remainder of the sum of its digits in base $14$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of [omega divisibility](http://www.numberbases.com/omeganumber.html): In base $n$, a number is divisible by $n-1$ if and only if the sum of its digits is.  In our usual base-ten numbering system, this gives us the rule for divisibility by 9.  And in base 14, it gives us a rule for divisibility by 13.

Adding up the digits in $123456789\text{abcd}_{14}$ gives (decimal) 91, which is a multiple of 13 ($13 \times 7$).  Thus, the original number is a multiple of 13.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque: I would dispute that this question is a duplicate.  Your linked "already has an answer" question is about divisibility by 9 in normal base-10 arithmetic, while this one is about divisibility by 13 in base-14.  Sure, if you're familiar with alternate-base arithmetic, it's easy to recognize this as being basically the same problem, *but this may not be obvious to beginners*.

Comment: The [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242)  in the dupe closing comment (and also others, e.g. Arturo's) discuss the rules in arbitrary radix. It thwarts pedagogy and site organization to duplicate these simple arguments for random specific radices.