# What does $(4 \mod 100) \equiv (5 \mod 99)$ mean?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I came across the following example on [page 9](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee486/doc/chap1.pdf#page=9) of *Introduction to Arithmetic for Digital Systems* by Waser and Flynn:

> **Example 1.5**
>
> Suppose we have two $\mod 99$ $A'$ and $B'$, having the following operations performed $\mod 100$, and then corrected to $\mod 100$ and then to a $\mod 99$ result?
>
> (i) $A' = 47$, $B' = 24$; find $(A' + B') \mod 99$.
>
> ```
>     47
>    +24
>   -----
>    071    71 mod 100 ≡ 71 mod 99 = result
> ```
>
> (ii) $A' = 47$, $B' = 57$; find $(A' + B') \mod 99$.
>
> ```
>     47
>    +57
>   -----
>    104    4 mod 100 ≡ 5 mod 99 = result
>     +1
>   -----
>     05
> ```
>
> (iii) $A' = 47$, $B' = 52$; find $(A' + B') \mod 99$.
>
> ```
>     47
>    +52
>   -----
>    099    99 mod 100 ≡ 0 mod 99 = result
> ```

Could someone please help me understand why $4 \mod 100 \equiv 5 \mod 99$?

I know that $N \mod \mu \equiv M \mod \mu$, iff there exists an integer $K$ such that $N - M = K\mu$, but I don't know how to interpret congruence between two different moduli.

Comment: You need to read the first paragraph very carefully.

Comment: Take the 2nd example above, the result of adding is $104$ which is $4 $ modulo $100$ but, $104$ is $5$ modulo $99$. The process that is (poorly described & justified) is to take the addition value $104$ and use that to compute the result modulo $99$.

Comment: I also think there is a typo, I would guess that the modulus should be $\beta^n-1$ not $\beta^n$.

Comment: Gack this exposition (the original source, not OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a poor description (of the linear case) of *casting out $\,99$'s*, a radix (base) $100$ analog of casting out nines. Namely write the sum $s$ in radix $100$ as follow $s = 100\,h + u,\,$ so $\,h =\,$  hundreds digit, $u= $ units digit in radix $100$. Then $\!\bmod 99\!:\ \color{#c00}{100\equiv 1}\Rightarrow s = \color{#c00}{100}\,h + u \equiv h+u \equiv$ digit sum, e.g. for their 2nd example $\color{#c00}1\color{#0a0}{04}\equiv \color{#c00}1+\color{#0a0}{04}\equiv 5\pmod{\!99}.$ The same works for any size integer with radix $100$ digits $\,d_i,\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{align} n = f(\color{#c00}{100})\, = &\ \ d_k 100^k + \cdots + d_1 100 + d_0\\[.3em]
\Rightarrow\ n\equiv\,\ \ f(\color{#c00}1)\ \ \equiv &\ \ d_k+\cdots +d_1 + d_0\!\!\pmod{99}\end{align}\quad$$

For much further discussion on "casting out" mod reduction and divisibility tests see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242).

Comment: Thank you @Bill, that clears it up, I wasn't aware of casting out nines. One thing I'm still confused about is: what if we had a non-zero digit in the tens place? e.g. what if the sum $s$ had been $1099$, then wouldn't casting out nines have left us with $1000 \equiv (1 + 9 + 9) \mod 999 \equiv 19 \mod 999$ instead of $1000 \equiv 100 \mod 999$?

Comment: I presume the final $\beta^n$ should be $\beta^n-1$ in the linked page.

Comment: @use $\bmod 999\!:\ abcde\!f = abc\cdot 1000 + de\!f \equiv abc+de\!f,\, $ e.g. $123456\equiv 123+456\equiv 579\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a typographical error as well as some pretty rubbish notation ($=$ result?? No thanks).

There's two conventional (and closely related) ways of interpreting mod.  One is as an equivalence relation (congruence mod m) which is kind of how you have written it:
$$
a \equiv b \text{ mod } m \quad \text{if  $m|(a-b)$}
$$
(here, think of 'mod' as being attached to the relation $\equiv$, rather than either of the numbers).

The other way is as an operator on a number, that is $ a \text{ mod } m = b$ where $b$ is the unique number such that $m|(a-b)$ and $0\leq b \leq m-1$.  That's how this text is using it (but in that case it is confusing that they use $\equiv$).  Note however that in that case
$$
5 \text{ mod } 100 = 5 \text{ mod } 99 \neq 4 \text{ mod } 99.
$$
(They do this correctly in the other examples).

Comment: So right! The notation is utterly confusing. I feel bad for readers here, but you've done your best. +1.