# Fermat's little theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Obtain residue class of $7^{9999}$ modulo 100 using the Little Fermat theorem.

But I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: I would rather use Euler's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem

Comment: It can be done using just basic tools. But I believe that if we are going to use something related to Fermat's Theorem, we really want to use Euler's generaliation of Fermat's Theorem.

Comment: An hint on how to proceed with basic tools is to compute $7^4$ mod $100$ and then observe that...

Comment: Have you looked at the first link on the right-hand side? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/using-fermats-little-theorem

Answer (score 7):

First observe that
$$
7^{4}=2401\equiv1\bmod100.
$$
Now write $9999=4\cdot2499+3$ so that
$$
7^{9999}=(7^4)^{2499}\cdot7^3\equiv7^3=343=43\bmod 100.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $7^4 = 2401 \equiv 1 \bmod 100$. Now divide $9999$ by $4$ with remainder.

Answer (score 2):

You could notice that $7^8 \equiv 1 \mod 100$. This makes the problem a lot easier
$$7^{9999}\equiv 7^{9 \cdot 1111}  \equiv 7^{7} \equiv 43 \mod 100 $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ 4\:|\:7^{\:\!2}-1,\ 25\:|\:7^{\!\:2}+1\ \Rightarrow\ 100\:|\:7^{\:\!4}-1\:|\:7^{\:4\!\:N}-1\ \Rightarrow\ 100\:|\:7^{\:4\!\:N+3}-7^{\:\!3}$

Or: $\rm\ mod\ 4,25\!:\ \ 7^{\:\!4} \equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ mod\ 100\!:\ \ 7^{\:\!4}\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ 7^{\:\!3 +4\!\:N}\equiv\: 7^{\:\!3} (7^{\:\!4})^N\equiv\: 7^{\:\!3}$