# Why does $\equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ n)$ seem so important?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, multiplicative-order

I'm not great with math so please feel free to correct any mistakes in my question (or add more examples).  I'm a software engineer and have recently wanted to better understand the maths behind RSA and Diffie Hellman.  The more I learn, the more I get sucked into the wikipedia vortex, and the more this keeps coming up.

Around every corner there seems to be a theorem, formula, or technique where $x \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ n)$ is of fundamental importance and I don't understand what property it has that makes it so special (compared to, say, $x \equiv 0\ (\text{mod}\ n)$ or something similar).

For example:

- Fermat's Little Theorem $a^{p-1} \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ p)$
- Euler's Theorem $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ n)$
- Modular Multiplicative Inverse $a\ x \equiv 1 (\text{mod}\ m)$
- Multiplicative Order  (the smallest $k$ where $a^k \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ n)$)

What's the nature of this equivalency that makes it so pervasive among modular arithmetic and primes?  Why don't other equivalencies show up more often like $\equiv 0\ (\text{mod}\ n)$?

Perhaps a new question altogether . . . why isn't it possible to have relative coprimes where there is no $k$ where $a^k \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ n)$?

Thanks!!

Comment: If $a$ and $n$ are coprime then look at the sequence $\{a,a^2,a^3,\dots\}\pmod n$. As there are only finitely many classes $\pmod n$ these can't all be distinct.  Hence we can find $i< j$ with $a^i=a^j\pmod n$. But then $a^{j-i}=1\pmod n$.

Comment: I apologize for answering nearly two years after the question was posed, but I saw this question, and thought I'd chime in. I'm no expert on number theory, but my understanding is that if you have a number $x$ equivalent to 1 (mod $n$), then you can ensure that $x$ is relatively coprime to $n$. This wouldn't occur if $x\equiv 2$ (mod $n$) for instance. One particularly useful theorem is that $x\equiv 1$ (mod $y$) implies that there exist $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax+by=1$. This is used to prove several other theorems, like perhaps the ones mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't have enough rep to comment, otherwise I would have just posted  [this link to RSA python 3 code](https://github.com/user-name-is-taken/RSA---pyhon-3) in a comment. However, since this is an answer, I'll answer. $p+1≡1\ mod\ p$ is a simple way to express that $p+1 \neq p\ mod\ p$. This might seem obvious, but some pretty cool proofs rely on this, like [Euclid's proof of infinite primes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQmdHpvfyJs). Furthermore, $p-1≡p-1\ mod\ p$ is pretty ugly.

for more information see:

- [primality testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) for computing $x^y mod\ p$ extremely fast using [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) (many computer languages, like [python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#pow), implement modular exponentiation for you).

  - [this simple example of modular exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/using-fermats-little-theorem)
- [this worksheet](http://www.tkiryl.com/teaching/aa/les092603.pdf) on Fermat's little theorem